# How is the change of ring functor via tensor products defined?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

If $f:A\rightarrow B$ is a map of rings and  $f^*:\text{Mod}_A\rightarrow\text{Mod}_B$ is the change of rings functor between modules defined by $M\mapsto M\otimes_A B$, why is $M\otimes_A B$ a B-module?

Answer (score 0):

$M\otimes_A B$ is a $B$-module because elements from $B$ can act on the right component of the tensor product. In particular, if $m\otimes b$ is a simple tensor and $c\in B$, then we can define the action $c\cdot (m\otimes b) = m\otimes (cb)$, and then extend additively to define it for all elements of the tensor product. If $c = f(a)$ for some $a \in A$, then $m\otimes (cb)= m\otimes (f(a)b) = (am)\otimes b$, but in general the $c$ cannot go over the $\otimes$ if it is not in the image of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

*Let $\tau: B\times M\to B\otimes _AM$ be the canonical $A$-bilinear map, and fix $e\in B$.*

The map $\eta_e: B\times M\to B\otimes _AM$ defined by $(b,m)\mapsto eb\otimes m$ is $A$-bilinar, yielding an $A$-linear map $$\mu_e :B\otimes _AM\to B\otimes _AM.$$

*Fix also $f\in B$.*

- $$(\mu_e+\mu_f)\circ \tau=\eta_e+\eta_f=$$ $$=\eta_{e+f}=\mu_{e+f}\circ\tau,$$ hence $\mu_e+\mu_f=\mu_{e+f}$.
- $$\mu_e\circ\mu_f\circ \tau=\mu_e\circ\eta_f=$$ $$=\eta_{ef}=\mu_{ef}\circ \tau,$$ hence $\mu_e\circ\mu_f=\mu_{ef}$.
- $$\eta_1=\tau,$$ hence $\mu_1$ is the identity.

*In conclusion, the fact that $\mu_e$ is $\mathbb Z$-linear for all $e\in B$, with the three points above, shows that $B\otimes_AM$ is a $B$-module with action $e\cdot u=\mu_e(u)$ on $u\in B\otimes_AM$. Moreover the $A$-linearity of $\mu_e$ guarantees that the action of $B$ is compatible with the $A$-module structure, i.e. $B\otimes_AM$ is a $(A,B)$-bimodule.*